# Can't see updated values in of panResponder callbacks

Tags: javascript, react-native, logic

In the onPanResponderMove callback, the second log consistently shows 0, regardless of trying dozens of different variations. My goal is to pass a state variable to this callback, but the default value of 0 keeps showing up. I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.

```
const [activeSectionIndex, setActiveSectionIndex] = useState(0);

const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

const generatePanResponders = (sectIndex) => {
  return activeTasksList.map((data, index) => {
    let gestureState = null;

    // The value seems correct here
    console.log(sectIndex);

    const createPanResponder = (currentSectIndex) => {
      return PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onPanResponderGrant: (_, gs) => {
          // ...
        },
        onPanResponderMove: (_, gs) => {
          if (gestureState) {
            // However, this always logs 0?
            console.log(currentSectIndex);
            myFunc(currentSectIndex);
          }
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (_, gs) => {
          // ...
          myFunc2(currentSectIndex);
        },
      });
    };

    const panResponder = createPanResponder(sectIndex);

    return panResponder;
  });
};

var panResponders = useRef(generatePanResponders(activeSectionIndex)).current;
```

Why is the second log behaving unexpectedly?